# WebView with NSShadow slowdown

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I have a webview that shows some animated boxes, but it slows down and lags horribly when I put a drop shadow in the view. Without the shadow, the webview contents animate smoothly.

*I achieved a similar effect as safari/chrome when you do a elastic scroll with the touchpad. Looks nice! But doesnt run as smooth as in my inspirations.*

Here is the snippet of the shadow setting:

```
NSShadow *dropShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
[dropShadow setShadowColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
[dropShadow setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(0, 0)];
[dropShadow setShadowBlurRadius:5.0];

[webview setWantsLayer: YES];
[webview setShadow: dropShadow];

[dropShadow release];
```

--

**My question is: How can I work around this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call `setWantsLayer:YES` on a `WebView`. Layer-backed web views are unsupported. This was actually pointed out in the 10.5 release notes and has not changed, unfortunately. You'll need to come up with an alternative solution.

Comment: Very unfortunate. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: How are you creating the boxes in the WebView?

Comment: There is just a webview filling the entire window, and I call this code in the "awake from nib" selector. That's it... I made the entire app interface inside the webview, not using other cocoa stuff.

Comment: I see. In that case, you should be able to just use CSS to create the shadows on your boxes. See http://www.webkit.org/blog/86/box-shadow/

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I want a shadow *behind* the webview, so it will look like safari and chrome when you pull beyond the scrollable area in Lion.